# Batch file that runs only during a specific time

Tags: time, batch-file, range

I would like to run a batch only during a specific time of the day (range).

For instance the idea would be to have have it run from 07:00AM to 06:00PM.

I know that `%TIME%` returns current time, what's missing now is a way to check this value and if she's on the range provided the batch will execute, if not the batch will stop there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (Win7):

> for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do if %%a geq 7 if %%a leq 18 echo hello

You can change `echo hello` to anything like `goto ok` and the next two lines would be for example `goto end` and `:ok`.

Don't forget to paste it to a batch file or use %a instead of %%a if you try it directly in command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however something is strange, 

I changed the echo hello by goto email (I would like to send an email or not) then written a section called :email with the option to send out the mail. after goto end

Then at the end :end

However the email is always sent out even if we are outside the time range...

Looks like this :


for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do if %%a geq 7 if %%a leq 18 goto email


:email

REM ** Activate the email**

cmd /c sendemail -f email1 etc..."

goto end


:end

Comment: Another question, can we check also the day to run it only from Monday to Friday for i.e. ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry. Maybe you should open new question for it.